# Scala newbie - if-else

Tags: scala

A scala method gets an input and should operate either on the input directly or a calculation of it, for instance consider the following code:

```
def foo (b : Boolean, input : Any): Unit ={
  val changedInput = {if (b) input else bar(input) }
  dowork (changedInput)
}
```

Is it appropriate to use an anonymous function like in the example above or there another syntax?

Comment: There is no anonymous function in that example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no anonymous function in your example. And the code you write, IMO, is just fine.

I guess you regard `{if (b) input else bar(input) }` as anonymous function. It is called "block" in scala, which is just a expression whose value is the last expression contained in the block. For instance,

The value of `{ expr1; expr2; expr3}` is the value of `expr3`. 
So your code can just be written as

```
def foo (b : Boolean, input : Any): Unit ={
  val changedInput = if (b) input else bar(input)
  dowork (changedInput)
}
```

since there is only one expression in your block.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(b: Boolean, input: Any): Unit =
  dowork(if (b) input else bar(input))
```

Answer (score 0):

This `{}` is used for multiline code block and are optional for one line code. Anonymous function in Scala looks like this `val square = { x: Int => x * x }`

```
def foo (b : Boolean, input : Any): Unit = {
  val changedInput = if (b) input else bar(input)
  dowork (changedInput)
}
```